# Domino: When forwarding a copy of all inbound emails to an external email address, the original recipient is missing

Tags: email, lotus-domino, forwarding

Our service needs a copy of all inbound emails from the client.  This is not a problem for Exchange, Gmail and other email client - server combos.

However, our clients using HCL (formerly IBM, lotus) Domino / Notes combo are able to forward the email, but Mailgun (our inbound mail system) is rejecting the emails because they do not include the original recipient in the envelope.

Does anyone know how to forward a copy of all emails from the Domino server in a way that INCLUDES the original sender?

Comment: There are some contradictions in your description (I think), so an example could be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Domino has a mail journaling feature that is tied into mail rules. One of the journaling methods sends messages to the journal via email. That method is normally used to store in a Notes/Domino mail-in db, but I think it could send the messages to an external destination such as yours. If you had asked 10+ years ago,, when I worked on a mail archiving system for HP, I would have known for sure. Now, I don't recall the details but suggest you look into it. If you want people with more current Domino mail admin expertise to assist you, I suggest you ask on SeverFault instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mail is received by a Domino server for person user A. You would like to have an exact copy of that mail sent to your mail server. That can probably be accomplished on the Domino server using a mail group.

Example:

- a mail is sent to sales@acme.org
- sales is a standard mailbox for someone

The following changes can be applied:

- create a mail group called salesgroup
- add sales to the group
- add youraddress@yourcompany.org to the group

When a mail is sent to salesgroup@acme.org, the Domino server delivers the mail to every address mentioned in the group.

N.B. The Router Configuration document will have to be modified in order to permit an outside mail to be relayed to an outside address.